# pm2 and systemd on ubuntu can't daemon node app correctly

Tags: node.js, systemd, pm2

folks. I am implementing a node app on an Ubuntu server. The app uses a CAS 
server to fetch ticket. The codes like below:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session) {         // failed to create session
        return res.status(500).end();
    }
    if (req.session.uid) {      // user has logged
        return next();
    }
    if (!req.query || !req.query.ticket) {  
        // if a none-logged request has no query, it should be thought as 
        // the first request of the user, so it would be redirect to CAS 
        // server for authentication
        return redirectToCas(req, res);
    }
    var { ticket } = req.query;
    if (!ticket.startsWith('ST-')) {
        // This system self don't use query string. If a none-logged request
        // carries a none-CAS-standard query, it will be treated as illegal
        // and redirect to unauthorized page.
        return redirectTo401(res);  // unknown ticket
    }
    let originalUrl = LOCAL_SERVICE + url.parse(req.originalUrl).pathname;
    let path = `${CAS_SERVER}/serviceValidate?service=${originalUrl}&ticket=${ticket}`;
    (async () => {
        try {
            console.log(`${times++} original url:${originalUrl}`);

            let echo = await getResponseText(path);     // get xml response from CAS server
            let result = await parseXmlEcho(echo);      // set successful flag and fetch uid 
            if (result.success) {       // successfully pass the verification of CAS
                var hasPerm = await testPermission(result.uid);
                if (hasPerm) {          // test if user has permission in this system
                    req.session.uid = result.uid;
                    res.redirect(originalUrl);
                } else {
                    redirectTo401(res);
                }
            } else {
                //res.status(401).end('authorized');
                redirectTo401(res);
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            //res.status(401).end('没有授权！');      // unauthorized
            redirectTo401(res);
        }
    })();
}
```

The above codes belongs to auth.js. And the main entry port the app.js likes this:

```
// provide public resources
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'some.ico')))
    .use('/public', express.static('public'));

// check session
app.use(session({
    name: 'certain-name',
    secret,
    store: new MssqlStore(storeConfig),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: false
    }
}));

// authenticate
app.use('*', auth)              // authenticate
    .post('/end', api.end);     // logout
    .... serve index.html and other resource here
```

Now I have implemented codes on my Ubuntu server. And when I started the app in Putty terminal using "node app.js", all work fine. But when I started it using both PM2 or systemd(I configed it under the direction by Chris Lea's [blog](https://nodesource.com/blog/running-your-node-js-app-with-systemd-part-1/)
), the app break down and the browser echo "Cannot GET /index.html". After viewing the log(systemctl status myappname) the system but reported index.html has been served. 
What's the differences between spawning process by directly knocking in 'Node app' in terminal and starting it using systemd or PM2? Is there some further configurations needed for spawing Nodejs+CAS?

Comment: If you do a `pm2 list`and a `pm2 monit`, do you see the app running? Can you check pm2 logs?

Comment: I added my app to PM2 by editing ecosystem.config.js. I started the app and accessed main page but got just no logs.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out detailed flow steps of the app after inserting a bundle of log statements. The problem is caused by specifying false path of static resources. There are two rows in my app which reference express static middle-ware. One is before and the other is after authentication.

```
use('/public', express.static('public')) // serve two tiny images and noperm.html
...authenticate
use('/',express.static('client/build')) // serve homepage
```

Both of the two statements bundle the resource path with the current directory. When I connected to Ubuntu with putty I unconsciously always go into the path where contains the app and then start the app with node. Because the current path is the root of the app so that both current-path+'public' and current-path+'client/build' work out correct resource path and the app goes happily. But when I started the app using PM2 or systemd, the base directory change(I haven't verified but just guess) to the root path of PM2 or systemd, so that all static resources can't correctly spotted any more and the app run failed.
After I have amended codes to calculate static resources path with path.join method problem gone.
So there really is something different between starting app from PM2 and Node, at least the default path is.